# get hourly weather and weather warning using tasker/zooper

Tags: tasker, weather

I have an unrooted Nexus 5.

I am using zooper for my homescreen, but with tasker, my knowledge is limited.

I am trying to get (3-) hourly weather and weather warnings. I have found [this blog post](http://blog.artesea.co.uk/2014/06/one-line-weather-summary.html) that do talks about hourly weather, but with my limited knowledge with tasker, I am unable to create the profile he talks about.

May I get some help?

**EDIT**

Izzy, Thanks for your detailed reply. I tried to follow your advice and got:

```
Weather (26)
A1: Flash [ Text:Getting Weather Long:Off ] 
A2: HTTP Get [ Server:Port:https://api.forecast.io Path:forecast/<API KEY>/%allatitude,%allongitude Attributes:units=uk Cookies: User Agent: Timeout:10 Mime Type: Output File: Trust Any Certificate:Off ] 
A3: If [ %HTTPR eq 200 ]
A4: JavaScriptlet [ Code:info=JSON.parse(global("HTTPD"));flash(info.minutely.summary); setGlobal("FORESUM", info.minutely.summary) Libraries:Auto Auto Exit:On Timeout (Seconds):45 ] 
A5: Zooper Widget Pro Variable [ Configuration:#TWtxt# = %TIME %FORESUM Package:org.zooper.zwpro Name:Zooper Widget Pro Variable Timeout (Seconds):0 ] 
A6: End If 
A7: AutoLocation Location [ Configuration:Stopping Location Monitor
Location Report Name: Weather 
Update Type: No Power Package:com.joaomgcd.autolocation Name:AutoLocation Location Timeout (Seconds):0 ]
```

but when I tried to run that task (the play sign at the bottom of the page) I get java IO error (its blink and miss...so cant exactly say what it prompts)

Can you kindly have a look?

Comment: He talks about two profiles. So it might help if you [edit] your question, copy/paste the one you've got trouble with, and state what exactly your trouble is with it (if it's the general structure, pick the shorter one or just state so – I could then copy/paste it to an answer in a structured and explained way). Agreed, the formatting is a little unfortunate to someone new to tasker; rawly: "Profile" just states the name, "state/event" the condition, "Enter" the entry task, A1..An are the steps in the task.

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks for your comment, but there comes my first problem. Being a novice, I use tasker via its UI. I have no idea how I can copy/paste the profile. May you kindly help?

Comment: I'm using Tasker for years already, and never used it other than via its UI. Sure you can export/import tasks and profiles (which I use for backup/restore or transfering profiles between devices), but simple copy/paste is nothing I ever did (or would recommend; I prefer at least to rawly understand what's going on ;) But I take it there's no specific issue you're having, but it's rather general understanding. So I will take the shorter profile for explanation. In general, I highly recommend visiting their site and go for the manuals.

Comment: you are right, I am unable to create the profile in general, not that having any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take the shorter profile for an explanation on how to work with this kind of copy/pasted profiles – and am pretty sure once you've got the idea, you can deal with the other one as well. Instead of a simple copy/paste, I will apply some structure to it, and add some explanations:

> **Profile: Display Unlocked (61)**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - **Condition:** Event: Display Unlocked<sup>2</sup>
> - **Task:** Enter: Get Location For Weather (62)<sup>3</sup>
>
>   - A1: AutoLocation Location<sup>4</sup>
>       [ Configuration:Starting Location Monitor
>       Location Report Name: Weather
>       Update Type: Balanced Package:com.joaomgcd.autolocation Name:AutoLocation Location Timeout (Seconds):0 ]

For a starter: *Tasker* works with *profiles*, which are combining conditions (when should something be done?) with *tasks* (what should be done?). You also can have stand-alone tasks, which then could be triggered e.g. from shortcuts on your homescreen – but that's a different thing I won't discuss here. So:

**<sup>1</sup>** This line just tells you to create a new profile and give it a "speaking name" (must not necessarily be the same to the letter).

**<sup>2</sup>** When you named your profile, *Tasker* will automatically ask you to create a condition. There are different types of conditions: "events" (something that "happens in a short time frame", such as unlocking the display), and "states" (some rather "long-term status", such as being connected to a WiFi network). Depending on the condition type, the tasks also might be processed differently: tasks based on an "event" e.g. usually revert their changes back to the original state when the condition is no longer met. So in this specific case, you select "event" from the popup, and watch out for the matching category holding the "display unlocked" event, then select it.

**<sup>3</sup>** Once you've defined your condition, *Tasker* will ask you to create (and name) a "task". This is called the "enter task", as it's processed when *entering* the profile<sup>5</sup>. So the name to specify is up to you, "Get Location for Weather" is a suggestion wich you're free to accept. The "task editor" will popup then.

**<sup>4</sup>** A1..An in the linked tutorial specify steps inside the "enter task" you should add in this order. In our above example, this is just a single step: Selecting (and configuring) Jaos "AutoLocation" addon. So everything following inside the square brackets are configuration advices you should follow in the plugins popup/page, which will appear when you've selected it (located usually in "plugins" or "3rd party").

---

**<sup>5</sup>** There are also optional "exit tasks", which can be used to trigger actions when the condition is no longer met. As I described above, with tasks based on a "state condition", *Tasker* usually reverts stuff to what it was before (if you e.g. have a task increasing the volume to "level 7", and it was "level 5" before, *Tasker* will automatically restore it back to "level 5"). However, this a) might not always be what you want to happen, and b) with multiple profiles overlapping, it might be necessary to (re-)set things explicitely. Example: Profile A starts and sets volume from 5 to 7. Then profile B starts, setting volume to mute. If now profile A ends, it would restore volume to 5, which might not be what you'd like. Say it wouldn't do so on end, profile B would then restore to 7 – again not what you want if profile A is no longer active. So you might need a manual solution, e.g. restore volume to a level on the condition whether the other profile is still active or not.

---

I hope this example helped you getting started. For more, I definitely recommend you visiting the [Tasker Homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/), where you can find not only a UserGuide, but also several other Guides and tutorials, FAQs and more.